# How are the precise angles of a triangle found in terms of $\pi$ when the sides are given?

Tags: trigonometry

How are the precise angles of a triangle found in terms of $\pi$ when the sides are given?

Is there a general rule, formula or method that yields exact answers in terms of $\pi$?

I have the example ABC=$\sqrt5,5,\sqrt{40}$ and let's say for the sake of uniqueness that the sides are always given in size order.

As for my own efforts in this special case, I can inscribe ABC within the smallest right angle triangle containing it: $2,6,\sqrt{40}$ and yield angles such as $\arcsin\left(\frac6{\sqrt{40}}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\right)$ but to show this is $\pi/4$ is trickier.

Comment: Angles in terms of sides could be found with the cosine formula. $$\cos(A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$

Answer (score 1):

As Sonal_sqrt already pointed out, the angles may be found by using the cosine formula.

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be the angles at the vertices $A,B,C$. We have:

\begin{equation}
\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right),
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\beta=\arccos\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\right),
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\gamma=\arccos\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right)
\end{equation}.

Moreover,using the sine formula, we have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{a}{\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{b}{\sin(\beta)}=\frac{c}{\sin(\gamma)}=2r,
\end{equation}
where $r$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle.

Hope this is of any help.